# HTML5 WebSockets Only Work For Localhost

Tags: html, websocket

I am having a bit of a problem with HTML5 & WebSockets.

I have put together a very simple client / server application to pass strings to each other and all works well when I am accessing the client html page via a local file path or via http://localhost, however when I try and call it from http:// or http:// it doesn't seem to work.

The first thing the client does is check if the browser supports Web Sockets:

```
if (!window.WebSocket) {
        _Status.innerHTML = "Web Sockets not support by this browser";
        return;
    }
```

When I browse to the page with the local host address window.WebSocket is true, but when I use anything else, the page works but window.WebSocket is false.

Am I missing anything obvious? Is it an IE permissions/trust issue?

I am using IE10 and Windows 8 Consumer Preview.

I am out of ideas. Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets uses TCP protocol layer to connect.
Server opens Socket and Binds it to specific Port. Then it listening port and accepting connections.
If you are trying to connect to your server, make sure that you use right external IP and you probably need to set up Port Forwarding on your router to your computer, that router will know where to redirect packets.